# Why can't I open my JAR outside NetBeans?

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have built my project that has 5 JAR files including my project JAR file. I am unable to open the jar file of my project outside NetBeans. How can I run the jar file outside IDE and distribute to customers?

Comment: why not Jar all the Jars into one? http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a shell script (Linux/Mac) or batch file (Windows) with something like this to start your application:

```
java -cp jar1.jar:jar2.jar:etc YourMainClassName
```

Comment: for Windows user `;` as separator